# Is luwak coffee, involving coffee cheries partly digested by a small catlike animal, halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, food

> Kopi luwak... refers to the coffee that includes part-digested coffee cherries eaten and defecated by the [Asian palm civet]... a small catlike animal.  ... Kopi luwak is produced mainly on the islands of Sumatra, Java, Bali and Sulawesi in the Indonesian Archipelago. -- [Wikipedia]

Is Luwak coffee (kopi luwak) halal?

I used Google and the result is very confusing, there are two different views. One of it, the MUI (Indonesian Ulemas Council) says it is Halal, but there are some Ulama's who says it is haram to consume.

Do anybody has better explanation about it?

Answer (score -1):

Kopi Luwak isn't haraam as there's no Shari' reason for it to be.  Just because it's defecation of the Toddy Cat, it's still put through a process of change that makes the original state different.

Yes, defecation is impure, however chemical changes can happen and make it allowable.